# Gradle sync is failing as ImmutableMultiMap cannot access its super class

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Suddenly out of no where, my Android Studio decided to not build my project's gradle because of the following error -

**Cause: class com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMultimap cannot access its superclass com.google.common.collect.AbstractMultimap**

I tried searching the internet for a solution but there's little or absolutely no content available on the issue.
Any help will be highly appreciative.
Thanks a ton in advance!

Answer (score 1):

clean or rebuild your project...

Comment: The problem persists whenever I restart the Studio or when the gradle builds for a run!